# CSS Triangles Pointing to Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following markup which I got from [cssarrowplease](http://www.cssarrowplease.com/):

```css
.arrow_box {
 position: relative;
 background: #88b7d5;
 border: 2px solid #c2e1f5;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
 bottom: 100%;
 left: 50%;
 border: solid transparent;
 content: " ";
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 position: absolute;
 pointer-events: none;
}

.arrow_box:after {
 border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #88b7d5;
 border-width: 10px;
 margin-left: -10px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
 border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
 border-bottom-color: #c2e1f5;
 border-width: 13px;
 margin-left: -13px;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="btn1" />
<input type="submit" id="btn2" />
<input type="submit" id="btn3" />

<div class="arrow_box">My content goes here</div>
```

I'm not good in doing UI and would like to know what's the approach so that the triangle pointer of my div points in the middle of each button when I hover on them? Can this be done via HTML/CSS only or I need to apply javascript?

Comment: play with some values and you will get it ... like left for example

Comment: If you had the triangle as a part of the button then you could use a CSS only solution. But if you wanted to update the arrow position on the arrow_box when hovering over another element you'd need to use some JS.

Comment: You can use bootstrap tooltip to do that https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the left position of the arrow on hover (also hide it on non hover)

```css
.arrow_box {
  position: relative;
  background: #88b7d5;
  border: 2px solid #c2e1f5;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.arrow_box:after,
.arrow_box:before {
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  display: none;                  /* add this so arrow is hidden if no button is hovered */
}

.arrow_box:after {
  border-color: rgba(136, 183, 213, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #88b7d5;
  border-width: 10px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.arrow_box:before {
  border-color: rgba(194, 225, 245, 0);
  border-bottom-color: #c2e1f5;
  border-width: 13px;
  margin-left: -13px;
}

#btn1:hover~.arrow_box:after,  /* this means whilst button 1 is hovered style the after of any following siblings with the class arrow box */
#btn1:hover~.arrow_box:before {
  display: block;
  left: 30px;                  /* these are examples only, if you want it dead in the middle of the button, I would give the button a width so you know what the middle is */
}

#btn2:hover~.arrow_box:after,
#btn2:hover~.arrow_box:before {
  display: block;
  left: 90px;
}

#btn3:hover~.arrow_box:after,
#btn3:hover~.arrow_box:before {
  display: block;
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="btn1" />
<input type="submit" id="btn2" />
<input type="submit" id="btn3" />

<div class="arrow_box">My content goes here</div>
```